# MongoDB nested aggregation not finding inner collection

Tags: mongodb

I am new to Stack and MongoDB. I have adjusted my codes based on other posts but couldn't figure out where i went wrong. I have three collections. Microbe is connected to Activities (1 to M) and Activities to Bio-Activities (1 to M). I would like to show the nest from Microbe until Bio-Activities in the form of an array.

```
Microbe collection
{"_id": 1, item: "abc", species: 12, quantity: 2},
{"_id": 2, item: "jkl", species: 20, quantity: 1},
{"_id": 3}

Activities collection
{"_id": 1, code: "MON1003", item: "abc", type: "Monitor", repeat: 120, size: "27", resolution: "1920x1080"},
{"_id": 2, code: "MON1012", item: "abc", type: "Monitor", repeat: 85, size: "23", resolution: "1280x800"},
{"_id": 3, code: "MON1031", item: "jkl", type: "Monitor", repeat: 60, size: "21", resolution: "1920x1080"}


Bio-Activities collection
{"_id": 1, code: "MON1003", description: "bio 1", quantity: 120},
{"_id": 2, code: "MON1003", description: "bio 2", quantity: 80},
{"_id": 3, code: "MON1012", description: "bio 3", quantity: 60},
{"_id": 4, code: "MON1012", description: "bio 4", quantity: 70},
{"_id": 5, code: "MON1012", description: "bio 5", quantity: 170},
{"_id": 6, code: "MON1031", description: "bio 6", quantity: 270}
```

This is my code:

```
db.microbe.aggregate([ 
{ 
$lookup: 
{ 
from: "activities", 
localField: "item", 
foreignField: "item", 
as: "activities" 
} 
},{
$lookup: 
{ 
    from: "bioactivities", 
    localField: "code", 
    foreignField: "code", 
    as: "bioactivities" 
}
},{
    $unwind: "$activities"
},{
$group: {
    _id: "$_id",
    item: {$first: "$item"},
    species: {$first: "$species"},
    quantity: {$first: "$quantity"},
    activities: {$push: {
        id: "$activities._id",
        code: "$activities.code",
        item: "$activities.item",
        type: "$activities.type",
        repeat: "$activities.repeat",               
        size: "$activities.size",
        bioactivities: "$bioactivities"
    }
    }
}
}
]).pretty()
```

But I get this output which shows empty "bioactivities". Where did I go wrong?

```
    {
    "_id" : 2,
    "item" : "jkl",
    "species" : 20,
            "quantity" : 1,
            "activities" : [
                    {
                    "id" : 3,
                    "code" : "MON1031",
                    "item" : "jkl",
                    "type" : "Monitor",
                    "repeat" : 60,
                    "size" : "21",
                    "bioactivities" : [ ]
            }
    ]
    }
    {
            "_id" : 1,
            "item" : "abc",
            "species" : 12,
            "quantity" : 2,
            "activities" : [
            {
                    "id" : 1,
                    "code" : "MON1003",
                    "item" : "abc",
                    "type" : "Monitor",
                    "repeat" : 120,
                    "size" : "27",
                    "bioactivities" : [ ]
            },
            {
                    "id" : 2,
                    "code" : "MON1012",
                    "item" : "abc",
                    "type" : "Monitor",
                    "repeat" : 85,
                    "size" : "23",
                    "bioactivities" : [ ]
            }
    ]
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. "Order does matter", quoting Mongo's video.
Solution: I should $unwind my "activities" before I do a $lookup to "bioactivities". Here's the code.

```
    db.microbe.aggregate([ 
    { 
    $lookup: 
    { 
        from: "activities", 
        localField: "item", 
        foreignField: "item", 
        as: "activities" 
    } 
    },{
        $unwind: "$activities"
    },{
        $lookup: 
    { 
        from: "bioactivities", 
        localField: "activities.code",  
        foreignField: "code", 
        as: "bioactivities" 
    }
    },{
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            item: {$first: "$item"},
            species: {$first: "$species"},
            quantity: {$first: "$quantity"},
            activities: {$push: {
                 id: "$activities._id",
                 code: "$activities.code",
                 item: "$activities.item",
                 type: "$activities.type",
                 repeat: "$activities.repeat",              
                 size: "$activities.size",
                 bioactivities: "$bioactivities"
            }
       }
    }
    }
    ]).pretty()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a silly mistake which I think you overlooked.
In your second `$lookup`, `localField` should be `"activities.code"` like this,

```
{
$lookup: 
{ 
    from: "bioactivities", 
    localField: "activities.code", 
    foreignField: "code", 
    as: "bioactivities" 
}
}
```

This will give you output like following:

```
{
    "_id" : 2.0,
    "item" : "jkl",
    "species" : 20.0,
    "quantity" : 1.0,
    "activities" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 3.0,
            "code" : "MON1031",
            "item" : "jkl",
            "type" : "Monitor",
            "repeat" : 60.0,
            "size" : "21",
            "bioactivities" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : 6.0,
                    "code" : "MON1031",
                    "description" : "bio 6",
                    "quantity" : 270.0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: I still get empty "bioactivities" after adding the change. What mongodb version are you using?

Comment: I am using 3.4.10

Comment: I'm running 3.4.2. I deployed it on Mongo's free cluster which has 3.4.10 running and I do get "bioactivities" like yours. However, I noticed that only the first document is correct, with item="jkl". But the rest is showing documents that are not suppose to be there, with "code" : "MON1012".

Comment: Have run it on 3.6 but still getting wrong "bioactivities" documents. Any help?

Comment: That must be because you have 3 documents with {"code": "MON1012"} and one with {"code": "MON1031"} in the bio-activity collection.

Comment: I expect the second $lookup to filter by "code" between "activities" and "bioactivities". So if an "activities" has the code "MON1012", then only "bioactivities" with the same code would be listed under it.